# export some value from json key as new json object

Tags: javascript, php, json

get stucked on "converting" this javascipt code (from SO) to php.

considering `"AAA='111' BBB='222' DD='333' CC='dao@toto.fr'"` a value from previous json object key.

1 - Received this json from some API post

```
{
  "first_key": "first_value",
  "sec_key": "sec_value",
  "third_key": "AAA='111' BBB='222' DD='333' CC='dao@toto.fr'",
}
```

2 - expect to export Third_key value as new json like this

```
{ "AAA": "111", "BBB": "222", "DD": "333", "CC": "dao@toto.fr" }
```

So,

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var input="AAA='111' BBB='222' DD='333' CC='dao@toto.fr'";
var result={};
 input.split("'").forEach(function(value,i,arr){
  if(i%2===0) return;
  var key=arr[i-1].trim().replace("=","");
  result[key]=value;
});

 console.log(result);
</script>
</body>
```

got this in console, approximatively what i want:

```
Object { AAA: "111", BBB: "222", DD: "333", CC: "dao@toto.fr" }
```

expected output:

```
Object { "AAA": "111", "BBB": "222", "DD": "333", "CC": "dao@toto.fr" }
```

How can i get expected output in PHP? Search engine sent me to `json_encode/json_decode` functions without relation with what i'm looking for.

Comment: looks like you're trying to `stringify` a js object. Other than that in javascript a object key `bbb` is actually `"bbb"`

Comment: Regarding javascript, it's maybe ok to stringify , but looking for php method to get expected output from var input  .

Comment: are you asking how to do the same in php after getting json from api ?

Comment: Yes @Talal. if it's possible.

Comment: so we are working with lets say ```$third_key = "AAA='111' BBB='222' DD='333' CC='dao@toto.fr'";```

Comment: Exactly, @Talal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can do this quite simple using a regex to extract the name and value and then use `array_combine()` to combine the results of this into an associative array, then `json_encode()` the resultant array...

```
$third_key = "AAA='111' BBB='222' DD='333' CC='dao@toto.fr'";
preg_match_all("/(\w*)='(.*?)'/", $third_key, $matches);

print_r($matches);

echo json_encode(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

This gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AAA='111'
            [1] => BBB='222'
            [2] => DD='333'
            [3] => CC='dao@toto.fr'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AAA
            [1] => BBB
            [2] => DD
            [3] => CC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111
            [1] => 222
            [2] => 333
            [3] => dao@toto.fr
        )

)
{"AAA":"111","BBB":"222","DD":"333","CC":"dao@toto.fr"}
```

The `print_r($matches);` is only there to show how the regex is splitting the original string into it's parts, and what the last line works with to create the end array.

Comment: thats what i was thinking but i couldn't wrap up the regex part. good answer

Comment: Great @Nigel Ren, that what exactly what i'm looking for. :)